# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0

Tags: java, android, uri

I'am developping an android app that receive an image url from java server, load image and then display it

after receiving the server response I get this error

```
   java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:  http://farm1.static.flickr.com/131/371306796_7e18d505fb_b.jpg
```

So how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 36):

As you can see there is a space in this url:

" http://farm1.static.flickr.com/131/371306796_7e18d505fb_b.jpg"

> So how to fix this problem?

Probably removing the space will fix it.

Comment: with trim() method maybe? beacuse i can't removing it manually  
I will try this

Comment: @nawara `trim()` will most probably work in this case, but this is what I call `being a doctor who tries to cure the symptoms`. If you get more time on it, try to fix the cause (parser? server sending url with space?).

Answer (score 3):

The java.net.URI class can help; in the documentation of URL you find

Note, the URI class does perform escaping of its component fields in certain circumstances. The recommended way to manage the encoding and decoding of URLs is to use an URI

Use one of the constructors with more than one argument, like:

```
URI uri = new URI(
    "http", 
    "http://farm1.static.flickr.com", 
    "/131/371306796_7e18d505fb_b.jpgf",
    null);
URL url = uri.toURL();
```

**the single-argument constructor of URI does NOT escape illegal characters**